# Kafka connection error when using KafkaJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I have installed Kafka on my local dev machine based on the instructions here:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart

I am able to produce and consume messages when running the .sh files as explained in the above link.

However, when trying to connect to Kafka from a nodejs app using KafkaJS, the following error is logged in the Kafka Server :

```
[2020-05-15 09:07:41,210] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=0] Unexpected error from /127.0.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369295617 larger than 104857600)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:448)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:398)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:861)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:760)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The producer code is as below:

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
    brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
})

const producer = kafka.producer();

await producer.connect()
```

Any ideas why it is not working from Nodejs code, but working when running the .sh files?

Comment: I switched to kafka-node and its working fine